# OpenInviter contact export request rejected by Gmail

Tags: php, gmail, openinviter

I have installed Openinviter successfully on my shared server.

I tried to get contacts from Gmail, Yahoo and Facebook, but it always return an error such as:

> Login failed. Please check the email and password you have provided and try again later

I also got an email from Gmail team that said:

> Suspicious sign-in prevented

Please help me to sort out this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have just encountered the same issue.  I granted the application the privilege in gmail, then the code can retrieve the contact list.  However, this stops me from using this code, as most of my users will not understand how...

Answer (score 0):

The Gmail team message isn't an OpenInviter problem. It just means that the IP address/device of the login is new for your account, it's not what Google is expecting, so they blocked it to be safe. It could also mean that an invalid oAuth token was user to try to access the account, or a bad password, etc. (For security, they don't explain why they thought it was invalid.)

You should be able to authorize that IP address (your server address?) by logging in to the Gmail account and checking the login history.

Related posts from Web Applications area on StackExchange (probably a better place to discuss this):

- [Does Google's “Suspicious sign in prevented ” mean that my password
  is compromised?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/39759/does-googles-suspicious-sign-in-prevented-mean-that-my-password-is-compromis)
- [Gmail “suspicious sign-in prevented” message -
  is it legit?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/26600/gmail-suspicious-sign-in-prevented-message-is-it-legit)