# import contacts in php from yahoo and hotmail

Tags: yahoo, hotmail

I want to import contact from yahoo and hotmail accounts using PHP in my application. I have google it alot but there is no specific answer is available to my problem. Every answer has some issues. Please help me in solving this problem.

I have got the secret keys for both.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use the OpenInviter open source solution ([openinviter.com](http://openinviter.com)), and it has done well for us. The community keeps it fairly up-to-date when 3rd party apps change their interfaces.

Comment: I have used this but I received the mail that the application accessing your account is suspicious.

Comment: @user2310840 Where did the email come from (Hotmail, Yahoo, Gmail), and what exactly did it say? It's probably due to your authentication method, not the OpenInviter code itself. See this related post re: Gmail, your situation may be similar: [OpenInviter contact export request rejected by Gmail](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11923185/openinviter-contact-export-request-rejected-by-gmail)

Comment: The email come form the provider whom email id, I am using for importing contacts.